# truncate headings when they have macros in them

Tags: header-footer, titlesec, xstring

EDIT: @egreg, I copy-pasted your document with `\expandonce`, but if I put a subsection with a macro inside, `\subsection{\textit{EE} LEFTshort subsec}`, then I get the error `Missing control sequence inserted. \end{document}`.

I also tried the `fit`option of `truncate`, `\usepackage[fit]{truncate}`, but, **with a small value for the length**, `\truncate{3em}{\subsectiontitle}`,  it does not solve the problem for the odd (left) side, because the header still go in the (physical right) margin.

THe `fit`option works better when I use long length, such as `\truncate{11em}{\subsectiontitle}`.

====================================

I try to use `titlesec` and `truncate` and `xtring` to truncate my long section headers, but my section titles can have `\textit{}` and other macros in them, a situation which breaks `\StrLeft`.

the problem with `\truncate` is that, **when the subsection header is smaller than the limit I assign truncate to**,  it positions the subsection header far away from the margin.

here the illustration with `\truncate`

[image: truncate]

- the command `\StrLeft` is good, because it glues the truncated header to the (physical right) margin
- the command `\StrLeft` breaks when my titles have macros
- the command `\StrLeft` is bad since it truncates up to the letter, not whole words
- the command `\StrLeft` is bad since it  has not the three little dots `...`
- the command `\truncate` is good since it never breaks and truncates at words, not letter
- the command `\truncate` is not positioned to the right like for `\StrLeft`
- the command `\truncate` is bad because it can go beyond the limit of the `\makeheadrule` [which I do not want]

here is the file

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,12pt]{article}
%\documentclass[oneside,a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{german}


\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[extramarks]{titleps}

\usepackage{truncate}
\usepackage{xstring}
\settitlemarks*{section,subsection}

%%\makeatletter
%%\def\setIn#1{\@setIn#1\@nil}
%%\def\@setIn#1#2\@nil{%
%%Input One: #1\par
%%Input two: #2%
%%}
%%\makeatother



\newpagestyle{MYSTYLE}{%
\widenhead[1cm][1cm]{1cm}{1cm}

\renewcommand{\makeheadrule}{\rule[1em]{\linewidth}{0.15ex}}
\renewcommand{\makefootrule}{\rule[1em]{\linewidth}{0.1ex}}


%% FIRST THE RIGHT SIDE [EVEN SIDE] THEN THE LEFT SIDE [ODD SIDE]
\sethead
[%
\large\thesection\#\truncate{8em}{\sectiontitle}%
]
[]
[%
\large\firstextramarks{subsection}\thesubsection\#
%\StrLeft{\subsectiontitle}{25}
\truncate{14em}{\subsectiontitle}
{+\thepage}%
]
{%
{\normalsize\thepage+}
\large\thesection\#\#\truncate{8em}{\sectiontitle}%
}
{}
{%
\large\firstextramarks{subsection}\thesubsection\#\#%
%\StrLeft{\subsectiontitle}{11}%
\truncate{11em}{\subsectiontitle}
}

\setfoot[][][]{}{}{}
}


\begin{document}

\pagestyle{MYSTYLE}
\section{\textit{EE} raha je hlavní a  současně největší město České republiky a }


\subsection{LEFTshort subsec}

\newpage

\subsection{RIGHT looo oooo nnn nnnn nnng ggg subsection title}

\newpage
\section{\textit{EE} raha je hlavní a  současně největší město České republiky a }



\subsection{LEFT looo oooo nnn nnnn nnng ggg subsection title}

\newpage
\subsection{ RIGHT Short subsec title}





\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry for the typo: it was `\expandarg`, not `\expandonce`

Answer (score 1):

Issue `\expandarg`; but in my opinion it's better *you* provide the abbreviated version.

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{czech}


\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[extramarks]{titleps}

\usepackage{truncate}
\usepackage{xstring}

\expandarg

\settitlemarks*{section,subsection}

\newpagestyle{MYSTYLE}{%
\widenhead[1cm][1cm]{1cm}{1cm}

\renewcommand{\makeheadrule}{\rule[1em]{\linewidth}{0.15ex}}
\renewcommand{\makefootrule}{\rule[1em]{\linewidth}{0.1ex}}


%% FIRST THE RIGHT SIDE [EVEN SIDE] THEN THE LEFT SIDE [ODD SIDE]
\sethead
[%
\large\thesection\#\truncate{8em}{\sectiontitle}%
]
[]
[%
\large\firstextramarks{subsection}\thesubsection\#
\StrLeft{\subsectiontitle}{25}
{+\thepage}%
]
{%
{\normalsize\thepage+}
\large\thesection\#\#\truncate{8em}{\sectiontitle}%
}
{}
{%
\large\firstextramarks{subsection}\thesubsection\#\#%
\StrLeft{\subsectiontitle}{11}%
}

\setfoot[][][]{}{}{}
}


\begin{document}

\pagestyle{MYSTYLE}
\section{\textit{EE} raha je hlavní a  současně největší město České republiky a }


\subsection{LEFTshort subsec}

\newpage

\subsection{RIGHT looo oooo nnn nnnn nnng ggg subsection title}

\newpage
\section{\textit{EE} raha je hlavní a  současně největší město České republiky a }



\subsection{LEFT looo oooo nnn nnnn nnng ggg subsection title}

\newpage
\subsection{ RIGHT Short subsec title}

\end{document}
```

[image]